# Get Json Data from WebMethod to Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, web-services

I wanted to get Json data from web method.In here i wanted to get News & Speaker both data but here only working News only.(Unable to get Speaker )

Here is my Stored Procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[LoadDayEvents] 
@Date date
as 
begin
select News,Speaker from Eventstbl
where DateToBePublished = CONVERT(date, @Date)
end
```

Here is my Web Method

```
 [WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
public static string SelectEventDate(string date)
{
    string News= "";
    string Speaker = "";

    try
    {
        SqlCommand comld = new SqlCommand("LoadDayEvents", conDB);
        comld.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comld .Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date);
        comld .Parameters["@Date"].Value = DateTime.Parse(date).Date;
        if (conDB.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conDB.Open();
        News = comld .ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        Speaker = comld .ExecuteScalar().ToString();  // Thisone is not working
    }
    catch (Exception ee) { }
    finally { conDB.Close(); }
    return News;
}
```

Here i use Ajax/Json to get it

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var urinews = '<%= ResolveUrl("WebMethods.aspx/SelectEventDate") %>';
        var localtime = new Date();
        var today = localtime.getFullYear() + '/' + (localtime.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + localtime.getDate();


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urinews,
            data: "{ date: '" + today + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#daily_news_Selection").append("<p>" + msg.d + "</p>");
            },
            error: function (x, e) {
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be partial. Where is the variable Verse defined?

Comment: Verse? i already remove that.

Comment: @ajp I wanted to get Speaker name in web method.News is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return custom class

```
 var newsAndSpeaker = new NewsAndApeaker() { News = News, Speaker = Speaker}; //or define a custom class that has these two properties
 return newsAndSpeaker;
```

On Javascript, you can access the two variables using

```
msg.d.News //news
msg.d.Speaker
```

Or, you could return a list of string

```
 var newsAndSpeaker = new List<string>() { News, Speaker}; //or define a custom class that has these two properties
 return newsAndSpeaker;
```

On Javascript, you can access the two variables as in like a array

```
msg.d[0] //mews
msg.d.[1] //speaker
```

If your question is why your second property is not getting populated, then title seems to be wrong

Comment: In the return part it shows the error "newsAndSpeaker" does not exists in the current context